# How do I save data in python(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, request

When I save the data to csv file only records with id 103 are saved and records having ids 101 and 102 are not available.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq

for vehicleList in range(101, 103):
    vehicleList = vehicleList + 1
    x = str(vehicleList)

    r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/vehicle/' + x + '/arrivals')
    r = r.text
    df = pd.read_json(r)

    df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: can you add the url complet? I mean in which case x ....101...102...?

Comment: First of all, fix your indentation. Second, it looks like you override your file after each loop.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the data before saving. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq

temp = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()

for vehicleList in range(101, 103):
    vehicleList = vehicleList + 1
    x = str(vehicleList)
    r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/vehicle/' + x + '/arrivals')
    r = r.text
    temp = pd.read_json(r)

    # some identifier here  
    temp['Type'] = x

    # concat
    df = pd.concat([df, temp]).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

You assign to a temporary DataFrame each loop `temp` and then add a unique id to denote the group `temp['Type']` and then concatenate to `df`. Once the loop is complete you save df with all iterations included.

Comment: thank you vey much ,I'm new to python so I'm missing so much.